# Mute sound script that remembers your choice

Tags: javascript

I have the following HTML:

```
<audio autoplay id="background_audio">
  <source src="https://sporedev.ro/pleiade/hol.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<a href="#" id="mute">Play/mute sound</a>
```

And the following JS:

```
var audio = document.getElementById('background_audio');

document.getElementById('mute').addEventListener('click', function (e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    audio.muted = !audio.muted;
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Here you can find a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qe86o3ga/).

What this script does is mute and resume playing an audio file that has the `background_audio` id.

I have succesfully implemented this solution in my [project](https://sporedev.ro/pleiade/hol.html). You can mute/play the sound by clicking on the icon with the cogs and the text "Setari" that can be found in the menu (it's in the middle of the last row).

How can I modify the script in order to set a cookie or create a session so that when the user mutes the sound on one page it can stay that way on the others as well?

I did some research on cookies in JS on SO and Google but couldn't figure out a solution.

Note that if the user reenables the sound then it should work again on every page.

I think that I need to create the cookie when clicking on the "`mute`" id. Then I'd need to verify if the cookie is set or not and, if it's set, assign that value stored in the cookie to audio.muted. If the cookie is not set then it should play the sound (easier said than done).

Answer (score 1):

When you click the button, add a cookie with the value `false`. On loading the page, check for the cookie.

Cookie lib's:
https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie
https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Comment: As I said, I did some research and I found how cookies work, however I'm a total noob when it comes to JS and, while I understand the theory, I fail to make it work. Could you please provide more details in your answer? Thank you!